# How can I produce this colored box in LaTeX?

Tags: color

I would like to create a LaTeX document with math problems and their solutions, where the statement of each problem goes inside a box like this one:
[image: This is the image of the box I want]

How can I produce this result (or a similar one) in LaTeX?

Comment: Take a look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: With the knowledge that [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) can produce this type of output, can you put some effort into trying to reproduce it? If you're still stuck after that, post the code that you've tried and the experts here will take that as foundation.

Comment: Of course, I wasn't trying for someone else to do all the work, I just needed a hint, I'm going to try now and see if I can figure it out. I had no idea that the **tcolorbox** package existed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case it helps someone else, this was my solution using the **tcolorbox** package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  colback=Magenta!5!white,
  colframe=Magenta!75!black,
  title={\centering Homework}]
The math problem should be here...
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The output is a colored box very similar to the one I posted in my question.

Comment: `tcolorbox` is a `tikz` based package, no need to load `tikz` beforehand, as well as `title={Homework},halign title=center` is a little bit cleaner than `title={\centering Homework}`

Comment: Thank you very much! :)